# How to get file path and name to save this file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml

I use open XML to export excel file. `SpreadsheetDocument.Create` requires a file destination.

I want to get this file destination from user similar to a `SaveFileDialog` in `Winforms`.
How I get file destination from user? I use Asp.Net 4.0 and OpenXML SDK 2.5 .

```
SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(destination, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
```

Comment: please give more info. Are you building a web site, a windows forms, etc...

Comment: So you want to get it from a [`SaveFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx)? What was the problem you encountered?

Comment: The question is tagged asp.net, I don't know if that's correct

Comment: SaveFileDialog used in windows forms, I want same thing in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

when a webserver is streaming a file down to the client, you don't have control of the destination folder. All you can do is:

- specify the contents type (to aid client in determining how to handle)
- specify filename
- (I think) tell the client browser to save the file vs. displaying it automatically in the registered application (for example, PDFs usually display in the browser, but setting up the streaming correctly could force Save File dialog instead)

If you need to "cache" the file ion the web server, you export to a server folder that your server process has write permissions to. Then you stream to the client - the client will get the prompt from their browser and save where they want.

Look at [`Server.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for example - it'll map virtual path to physical on your server. the question of permissions remains.

Depending on your particular case, you may be able to avoid saving to the server, if the export library has a way of returning a byte array or a stream, instead of saving to a file. In that case you just stream the return result to requester.

I am not familiar with the SDK you're using, but quick googling reveals this method of returning the document in a stream:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(stream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook, true))
    {
        ... work with the spreadsheetDocument, if needed

        ... prepare and stream to browser
    }
}
```

[Here's](http://dotscrapbook.wordpress.com/2011/08/26/creating-and-streaming-an-openxml-spreadsheet-using-the-net-sdk-and-asp-net-mvc/) one of the references to your SDK I found

Comment: Yes like you explain. But I didn't any solution on web to do this. How can I do it?

Comment: I am not familiar with the SDK you're mentioning. See if it has other overloads of the `Create` method, or other methods that A)Create your document and B) return the result in memory

Answer (score 0):

For this functionality even if you use open/save dialog, it would show the client locations not the server locations. So here question is, do you want to save that file to the client machine or at the server machine?

If you want to save it to client machine then first save it on the server by any name and location you want and then initiate a download after that. It will automatically prompt download dialog in the client browser and there user would be able to select the location and filename (depending on the client browser settings).

If you want to save it only on server then just before generating the spreadsheet, prompt user for entering the filename (on the page from where the request is generated). If some of your folders are accessible to user then you can also prompt user to select one of the folders, otherwise choose one as per your choice/requirement. Use the filename and the location to generate the spreadsheet.

Answer (score -1):

Use `Environment.SpecialFolder` enumerations. If you are looking for my documents then:

```
var destination = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(destination, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
```

Comment: I don't believe this answers the question - I think the OP wants to get the location from the user

Comment: Yes, I want to get location from user. User can save file location in any directory.